# Why am I receiving a heap buffer overflow runtime error

Tags: c++, iterator

I am doing Leetcode Problem 281. Zigzag Iterator, and I'm getting a run-time error that doesn't seem to be duplicatable on my local computer.

My code is

```
class ZigzagIterator {
public:
    ZigzagIterator(vector<int>& v1, vector<int>& v2) : v1{v1}, v2{v2}, it1{v1.begin()}, it2{v2.begin()}, first{false} {

    }

    int next() {
        int val{0};
        if(first || it1 == v1.end()) {
            val = *it2;
            it2++;
            first = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            val = *it1;
            it1++;
            cout << (it1 == v1.end()) << " " << *it1 << endl;

            first = true;
        }

        return val;
    }

    bool hasNext() {
        return (it1 != v1.end() || it2 != v2.end());
    }
private:
    // const vector<int> &v1;
    // const vector<int> &v2;
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it1;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it2;
    bool first;    
};

int main()
{
  vector<int> v1{1,2};
  vector<int> v2{3,4,5,6};
  ZigzagIterator i(v1, v2);
  while (i.hasNext()) cout << i.next();
}
```

The run-time error is:

```
AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000038 at pc 0x0000003843a6 bp 0x7ffeea8b3b50 sp 0x7ffeea8b3b48
```

I put in a print statement in the else clause of `next()`. On the second print, `(it1 == v1.end())` should be evaluating to `true`, but it seems to evaluate to `false` on leetcode and `true` on my local machine. Do I have a code error somewhere?

Comment: that's really a question, I don't know off the top of my head. In `ZigzagIterator(vector<int>& v1, vector<int>& v2) : v1{v1}, v2{v2}, it1{v1.begin()}, it2{v2.begin()}, first{false}` does v1.begin() read the input param v1 or the member v1 ?

Comment: @Jeffrey I am now wondering that myself too.

Comment: @Jeffrey This is probably one of the cases, or at least for me, where it's not good to be using the same parameter names for member var names. I usually don't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with all of the code that compares `it1` and `it2` to `v1` and `v2` in the class.  The `v1` and `v2` class members are copies of `v1` and `v2` from main, so you can't use `it1` and `it2` with them since `it1` and `it2` are iterators in main's vectors, not you classes.

You need to make the `v1` and `v2` members references so that everything is refering to the same vector.

Comment: Oh shoot, you're right. I actually had the references in their earlier, but it was crashing on a different test case. (see the 2 lines I commented out)

Comment: Or, OP could copy the vectors and make sure to point the iterators to the copy.

Comment: Actually, so I thought the code as it is was valid because I had thought when I initialized `it1` and `it2` that it would use the class member `v1` and `v2`? That doesn't seem to be the case. Is this undefined behavior, or does it always use the input parameters in the initialization list?

Comment: @user5965026 In `it1{v1.begin()}`, `v1` is the constructor parameter, not the class member.

Comment: @Jeffrey They could, but that would be a bad iterator.  It wouldn't modify the source vectors and you would have to get a copy out of it when done so you'd make at least 2 copies of your vector.

Comment: Ah I see. I think in this case I could've done `it1{this->v1.begin()}` and should work.

Comment: @user5965026 I beleive that works, but now your iterator points to a copy of the vector and if you do any modification through the iterator, it will not apply to the source vector.